# Basic Password System in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a basic login system that asks the user for a password. Here's a list of what it does:

- When you run the code it will open an Inputbox asking you for a password.
- There is one criteria: You have to enter a password of 8 characters. If you enter a password with less or more, it will give you an error message.
- If you leave the Inputbox blank or press Cancel, it will switch over to a Yes or No msgbox asking you if you want to quit the macro. Yes will close and No, will bring you back to the Inputbox.

I believe that there are many ways to optimize the code. Are there any suggestions?

```
Sub Userlogin(Password, ExitApplication)

Dim Confirm
Dim PasswordLength As Integer

' Password System
If Password = "" Then

    ' Loop until Password is correct.
    Do While Password = ""
        Password = InputBox("Enter your Password:", "Login")
        PasswordLength = Len(Password)

        ' Asks the user if they want to close the application.
        If Password = "" Then
            Confirm = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to close this application?", vbYesNo, "Confirm")
        End If

            If Confirm = vbYes Then
                ExitApplication = True
                Exit Do
                Exit Sub
            End If

            If Confirm = vbNo Then
                Password = ""
                PasswordLength = 8
                Confirm = ""
            End If

        ' Checks if the Password is 8 characters.
        If Not PasswordLength = 8 Then
            MsgBox "The Password must be 8 characters long." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Please Try again.", vbCritical, "Password Incorrect"
            Password = ""
        End If

    Loop

End If

End Sub
```

Main Sub is here:

```
Sub MainSub()

' Standard Dim's
Dim Username As String
Dim Password As String

Dim ExitApplication As Boolean

'_______________________________________________________________________________

' Set Values

ExitApplication = False
Username = CreateObject("WScript.Network").Username

'_______________________________________________________________________________

Call Userlogin(Password, ExitApplication)
    If ExitApplication = True Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Quick question. Is this meant to be an *actual* login system for something eventually, or just something you wanted to build?

Comment: Can you provide an example of how this `Sub` is being used? I.e. a couple lines of the calling code?

Comment: Hey, I will add the main Sub as well. This will be used with another system. IBM Personal Communications 3270, where it will check if the password is correct. I believe that I can optimize the code in "Sub Userlogin", I feel that It's well written but can be reduced somehow, or rewritten. I have other code that I am happy about. If you wish to see that, I can post more here.

Thanks for the answers so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be a function. `ExitApplication` shouldn't need to exist, it ought to be the function's return value.

```
Function Userlogin(Password, ExitApplication) As Boolean
```

If the function returns `True`, we proceed; if the function returns `False`, the calling code can act accordingly, and exit the application.

Kudos for declaring all the variables that you're using. If the module doesn't specify `Option Explicit` at the top, add it, and make it a habit: that will make VBA refuse to compile code that contains typos (/undeclared variables).

This is a bad, misleading comment:

```
' Loop until Password is correct.
Do While Password = ""
```

The comment says one thing, the code says another. Remove the comment, the only truth here is that of the code. Same with any comment that narrates *what* the code does: useful comments explain *why* the code does what it does, and let the code speak for itself about *what* it's doing.

Your members are implicitly `Public`. If `MainSub` is meant to be called from the outside, or as a macro, then make it *explicitly* `Public`, and then if `UserLogin` is meant to only ever be called from `MainSub`, then make it `Private`.

Your parameters are implicitly passed `ByRef`. In many languages including VB.NET, parameters are passed by value by default; it's a good idea to specify `ByRef` *explicitly* when you *mean* to pass them by reference.

The parameters are also implicitly `Variant`, but `Password` is meant to be a `String` and `ExitApplication` is meant to be a `Boolean`; it's also a good idea to consistently specify a type, even when that type is `Variant`, and *especially* when that type is NOT `Variant`: that way you'll allocate only the memory space you *need* to allocate; no more, no less.

The `Call` keyword / *explicit Call syntax* is obsolete, and only supported for backward compatibility. Instead of this:

```
Call UserLogin(Password, ExitApplication)
```

You can do:

```
UserLogin Password, ExitApplication
```

You're not using explicit `Call` for `MsgBox` and `InputBox` function calls; there's no need to use an explicit `Call` syntax for your own functions either.

You use a lot of `""` empty string literals; the `vbNullString` built-in constant is more efficient, since it's a null string pointer - as the following code in *immediate pane* demonstrate:

```
?StrPtr(""), StrPtr(vbNullString)
 456810912     0
```

See, VBA allocates a memory space for that empty string, but not for `vbNullString`. And if you call it 5 times...

```
?StrPtr(""), StrPtr(vbNullString)
 458095304     0 
 458097512     0 
 167896456     0 
 241904984     0 
 456810912     0
```

...you get a new address for it every time.

The `InputBox` result length-check is fine *in this case*, because an empty string is deemed invalid input - but the correct way to determine whether the user actually cancelled-out of the input box or meant to supply an empty string, is to verify the `StrPtr` string pointer value of the result: if that value is 0, the user cancelled the `InputBox`. If that value isn't 0, the user *meant* to supply an empty string.

This is interesting:

> ```
>     If Confirm = vbYes Then
>         ExitApplication = True
>         Exit Do
>         Exit Sub
>     End If
>
>     If Confirm = vbNo Then
>         Password = ""
>         PasswordLength = 8
>         Confirm = ""
>     End If
> ```

The two conditions are mutually exclusive, and the `Exit Sub` is heuristically unreachable code. It should be one conditional:

```
If Confirm = vbYes Then
    '...
Else
    '...
End If
```

It's not clear why `Confirm` is assigned to an empty string; it's a `Variant/VbMsgBoxResult` variable (*implicitly* declared as a `Variant`), so if anything it should be reset to 0, since `VbMsgBoxResult` is an enum type, and enum values are really just `Long` constants.

It looks particularly weird to see `Password = ""` immediately followed by `PasswordLength = 8` - seems you're giving different meanings to `PasswordLength`. At one point it stands for the *expected length*, and at another it stands for the *user input length*. This is confusing.

Remove it. All you *really* need is this:

```
Const RequiredLength As Integer = 8
```

And then:

```
If Len(Password) <> RequiredLength Then
```

It reads much clearer, and removes the magic value `8` from your code, too; the string message should also be using that `RequiredLength` constant, so that if it ever needs to change to `12` (it *probably* won't, but don't write code with the assumption that requirements never change - that's a terrible mistake to make), the message isn't going to be misleading.

Comment: Wow, this is just so incredible, that you took all of your time to type this! Thank you very much and a Merry Christmas! You should get some extra presents!
I learned a lot and I am very thankful for clearing up a lot of my confusion. I will implement all of the above, or as much as I can and post the result!